# С OpenServer почта отправляется, а на хостинге при отправке почты выдается ошибка Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. Как исправить?

Tags: php, phpmailer

С OpenServer почта отправляется, а на хостинге при отправке почты выдается ошибка Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. Как мне исправить эту ошибку? Для отправки почты я использую класс PhpMailer.

Настройки в классе PhpMailer:

```
FromName = (здесь домен моего сайта)
Host => 'smtp.gmail.com'
From => 'auto.web.messenger@gmail.com'
Username => 'auto.web.messenger@gmail.com'
Password => '*****************'
Port = 587
SMTPSecure = 'tls'
SMTPAuth = true
Mailer = 'smtp'
```

С этими настройками письма с OpenServer спокойно отправляются. Размещаю сайт на хостинге Beget и письма не отправляются.

Comment: Возможно на сервере порт закрыт по которому вы пытаетесь подключиться к SMTP

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий а что тогда делать? поменять порт на другое значение? а на какое?

Comment: так откройте нужный вам порт, информации как это сделать в гугле достаточно

Comment: открыть на чужом сервере? на распределенном. разве я могу такое сделать?

Comment: так дайте больше вводных данных, какой сервер,  скиньте код с настройками PhpMailer проще будет вам помочь

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий, я подредактировал вопрос, посмотрите.

Comment: Попробуйте порт `465` если не поможет включите расширенный режим ошибок `PhpMailer` с помощью функции `SMTPDebug = 4` и пришлите ошибку, еще можно попробовать переключить шифрование с tls на ssl с тем же портом 465. Возможно на сервере нет возможности использовать tls или ssl выполните команду `echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";`